# Sync firebase auth data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When a create a new firebase auth user using facebook or google, I received the user email and name but when I create a anonymous user and convert it to a facebook user the name still empty. How I to to sync the data from facebook or google in every new login?

Thanks in advance.

## AskFirebase

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `updateProfile` API. Here is an example with web on how to update the display name to the one in the provider data (assuming Facebook):

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
  displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].displayName
}).then(function() {
  // Display name updated successfully.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // error occurred.
});
```

To learn more about this API, refer to the [Firebase references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile).